# Specify interpolation times in boost::odeint

Tags: python, c++, boost, odeint

I have started using `boost::odeint` in my C++ code, and I think I'm missing a simple feature available in other integrators, namely Scipy's `odeint`.

`scipy.odeint` lets the user specify the times at which the state must be added to the output state history.`scipy.odeint` is a variable timestep integrator whose one-liner call looks like this (the state is integrated from the initial condition `X0` and interpolated/stored at the times specified in `times`)

```
X = scipy.odeint(dxdt,X0,times,atol = 1e-13,rtol = 1e-13)
```

where `X` is a matrix that has as many rows as there are elements in `times`

Basically, I am looking for a similar feature in `boost::odeint` in order to do two things:

1. Propagate a state from `t0` to `tf`, but only retrieve the final value of the state. I think I could write an observer only storing the state if the internal time satisfies `t == tf`, but this looks like a rather ugly hack. If I want to let the integrator choose the proper internal timestep to meet the tolerance values, storing intermediate states is a unnecessary burden.
2. Propagate a state from `t0` to `tf` but store the state at times specified in advance, that are not necessarily evenly distributed, in a similar fashion to the call to `scipy.odeint` hereabove, while also letting the integrator choose the proper internal timestep.

The closest I've been to achieving that is with the following

```
size_t steps = integrate_adaptive( make_controlled< error_stepper_type >( 1.0e-10 , 1.0e-16 ) , 
    dynamics , x , 0.0 , 10.0 , 1. , push_back_state_and_time( x_vec , times ));
```

The tolerances are met, but all the states are stored into `x_vec` by the observer, without letting me specify what the storage times should be.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the [`integrate_times`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/integrate_functions.html#boost_numeric_odeint.odeint_in_detail.integrate_functions.observer_calls_at_given_time_points) function:

It lets you specify a range of exact times for which the observer will be invoked, adjusting the step size to reach every time step exactly, if necessary.

Especially for adaptive methods, this is quite useful as it computes the solution at the exact times you specified while still controlling the time step size to not exceed the error bounds.

So your current call could be modified to something like

```
auto stepper = make_controlled<error_stepper_type>( 1.0e-10 , 1.0e-16 );
// std::vector<time> times;
// std::vector<state> x_vec;
// time tstep;
auto tbegin = times.begin();
auto tend = times.end();
integrate_times(stepper, dynamics, x, tbegin, tend, tstep, push_back_state(x_vec));
```

Comment: thanks. Very minor modification required to compile: add a default dt after t_end and before the observer. Something like the following will do:

`integrate_times(stepper, dynamics, x, tbegin, tend, 0.1,push_back_state(x_vec));`